# OwnProps Match and Params are undefined React-Router V3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

Trying to grab `id` from my url so that I can use it to fetchData on `componentDidMount`.  I'm also using it to set some state in the component to display information on the page.  However, both `ownProps.match` and `ownProps.params` keeps coming through as undefined.  I've tried a lot of things and all I can think of is that my / route is matching before thing/:id and it's causing an issue?

(I can use either and they fail like so).
`TypeError: this.props.params is undefined`
`TypeError: this.props.match is undefined`

Here are my routes:

```js
export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="login" component={requireNoAuthentication(LoginView)} />
    <Route path="register" component={requireNoAuthentication(RegisterView)} />
    <Route path="home" component={HomeContainer} />
    <Route path="thing/:id" component={ThingContainer} />
    <Route path="category" component={CategoryContainer} />
    <Route path="analytics" component={requireAuthentication(Analytics)} />
    <Route path="basic" component={requireNoAuthentication(BasicContainer)} />
    <Route path="*" component={DetermineAuth(NotFound)} />
  </Route>
);
```

mapStateToProps here (I've usually been commenting out `thing` until I can figure out the issue so can ignore that one).  Where I'm really seeing the issue is the const {id} portion.

```js
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  console.log(ownProps);
  return {
    data: state.data,
    token: state.auth.token,
    loaded: state.data.loaded,
    isFetching: state.data.isFetching,
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
    thing: state.things[ownProps.match.params.id],
  };
}
```

Here's where a piece of my component that's giving me the headache.

```js
 @connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
    export class Thing extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const { id } = this.props.match.params;
        this.fetchData();
        this.props.fetchThing(id);
      }
```

Btw, ownProps is coming through just fine when I `console.log` it above.  However it's missing any params/match which made me thing it was the route matching before it's intended match?  That would be ridiculous though because I couldn't ever do a nested route without losing my react-router params?

I'm to the point now where I've started at it so long that I'm losing focus.  Turning to some wonderful person for help!

Application is react 15.3, react-router v3, redux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see that you r rendering "ThingContainer" but ur class is an "Thing". Where r u using a HOC? Did you remember to pass all the props to the child ?

Example:

```
const ThingContainer = (props) => <Thing ...props />
```

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you so much!  I knew I was going crazy from looking at the code too long lol.  Sure enough, passed props through to my container and this.props.params showed right up.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `props` object returned from `mapStateToProps()` should include `ownProps.match` if you want to use it in your component. Either add it as another property, or merge `ownProps` into the object being returned.

Comment: I didn't test this out, but you're probably right that it could work!  I ended up going with the solution above as it was the intended function.  I realized I just wasn't passing my props through correctly =D.